# Simple IF Statement in MySQL isn't working

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns `id` and `name`.

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Test SET name='test' where id=1;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @affected_rows;
IF (@affected_rows > 0) THEN
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
END IF
```

It seems to be returning an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF (affected_rows > 0) THEN
>       COMMIT' at line 1 0 secs

Currently running MySQL 5.6.22

Comment: `If - else` could be used only in triggers and procedures. Are you using any procedures ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `if` as a control flow expression is only allowed in programming blocks -- stored procedures, triggers, and functions.

Second, the logic doesn't make sense.  If no rows are affected, there is no need to rollback the transaction.

To point out the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html):

> The `IF` statement for stored programs implements a basic conditional construct.

The term "stored programs" means some programming block.  Don't confuse this `if` with the MySQL function `if()`, which can be used in a query.